# Updating UICollectionView based on UIPicker's selected choice

Tags: ios

I have a collection view all set up and working and a uipicker all set up and working (`didSelectRow`)

I'm obviously new to this, and trying to figure out the best way to update the collectionview based on what I chose in the picker.

And by update the collectionview, I mean, let's say....change the labels of all the Cell's to the selected value of the uipicker. My main question is the communication aspect between the two components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1) Call `reloadData` in the delegate for the `UIPickerView` (`didSelectRow:InComponent:`).

2) Modify your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` in the `UICollectionViewDataSource` to setup the cell using the `UIPickerView`'s `selectedRowInComponent` method when setting up the `UICollectionViewCell`.

For example:

```
func pickerView(myPickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(myCollectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath atIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  // ...
  switch self.myPickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0) {
    case 0: dequedCollectionViewCell.text = "zero"
    case 1: dequedCollectionViewCell.text = "one"
    //...
    default: break
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: hmm how can i access `selectedRowInComponent` inside of `cellForItemAtIndexPath` . do i have to set the dataSource of the uicollectionview to be the picker?

Comment: @Volk Store your UIPickerView as a variable (or - alternatively store the selected index before calling reload in the picker view delegate).

Comment: i dont think reloadData exists on the uipickerview though (even in the docs?). what im currently doing that's half assedly working is storing the row as an instance variable, and whenever the user selects a row, i call `reloadData` on the collection view, and it kind of works but it doesn't fully reload everything. if i choose option A, it'll display option A. if i choose option B, it won't redraw the cells, it'll just draw option B on top of option A

Comment: @Volk To clarify you should be calling `reloadData` on your `UICollectionView`. Any time you call reload it will re-draw all the cells. Best thing to do is probably update your question with some code snippets.

Comment: ah yeah , okay i got it now Kevin thanks. the problem was i was doing an `addSubview` within the `cellforitematindexpath` which just kept drawing cells on top of each other :(